How to import openpgp.js in Deno?
As OpenPGP.js hasn't published in JSR yet, I need to import it via HTTP if I don't want to clone it to my local. Using:
import 'https://unpkg.com/browse/openpgp@6.0.1/dist/openpgp.js';

yields:
error: Expected a JavaScript or TypeScript module, but identified a Unknown module. Importing these types of modules is currently not supported.

It does publish on deno.land/x, but using:
import 'https://deno.land/x/openpgp@v6.0.1/mod.js';

yields "Module not found".
My ultimate goal is to upload Google API credentials on GitHub, via encrypting and decrypting the credentials.

The deno.land/x version doesn't seem right, because it uses extensionless imports. Did you try the npm version? Deno supports NPM packages, so JSR is not needed.
Alternatively, you can import the ESM browser version from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/openpgp@6.0.1/dist/openpgp.mjs

What you mean by "extensionless imports"? Surely you need the extension, right?

Take a look to the index.js file: https://deno.land/x/openpgp@v6.0.1/src/index.js?source
The imports doesn't have extension. This works in Node but not in Deno.

So you mean that it's not my fault in importing it incorrectly, but the package's fault for not converting to Deno correctly?

Yes. The package is not correctly published for Deno
